# SQL, cursor for one time initialization, Must declare scalar variable

Tags: sql-server

I am using a cursor to one time populate a table with all tenants that are in the tenants table. I want to make sure that the tenantId will be set with a name of General in my navigations table. But for some reason it thinks that my variable isn't set.

I tried the following code

```
**** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/

declare @tenantId int
declare @tenantName nvarchar(100)


DECLARE tenantCursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT Id, [Name]   
FROM [dbo].[Tenant]


OPEN tenantCursor;  
FETCH NEXT FROM tenantCursor  INTO @tenantId, @tenantName;  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
   BEGIN  

        print @tenantId
        print @tenantName
        SET @tenantId = @tenantId

        Insert INTO [dbo].Navigations ([Name, TenantId]) 
            VALUES ('Algemeen', @tenantId);

        GO

        FETCH NEXT FROM tenantCursor INTO @tenantId, @tenantName; 
   END;  
CLOSE tenantCursor;  
DEALLOCATE tenantCursor;  
GO
```

I got the follwoing error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 26
Must declare the scalar variable "@tenantId".

The structure of my tables
[image]

Any help will be much appreciated. 
Rodney

Comment: @HoneyBadger on the contrary, they *should* be used even though they are optional. They *are* required in many cases, eg when CTEs are used

Comment: @RodneyWormsbecher why a cursor? This looks like a simple `INSERT ... SELECT`

Comment: @HoneyBadger check Brent Ozar's [Give Your T-SQL a Semicolonoscopy](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/12/give-your-t-sql-a-semicolonoscopy/) and particularly Dan Guzman's [Always Use Semicolon Statement Terminators](https://www.dbdelta.com/always-use-semicolon-statement-terminators/).

Comment: Try to remove "Go" inside the cursor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is to just use SQL in the set based manner with which it is designed and run the following instead of your `cursor`:

```
insert into dbo.Navigations ([Name]
                            ,TenantId
                            ) 
select 'Algemeen'
      ,Id
from dbo.Tenant;
```

Outside of the above however, you shouldn't have a `go` in the middle of your `cursor` and you have missed some square brackets on your `insert`:

```
Insert INTO [dbo].Navigations ([Name, TenantId])
```

should be

```
Insert INTO [dbo].Navigations ([Name], [TenantId])
```